# Meaning of the preposition "in" in context

Tags: meaning

What does "in" mean in the following sentence? "NASA lanched the satellite. But several days in, something went wrong." Does it mean after several days?

Comment: "several days in(to the flight)..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Several days in

Expressions like this can be interpreted as equivalent to "after" ("several days after") in this case.

Typically, *in* would be used in an expression like this when it's relative to another given time period

> 4 hours into the 12 hour flight, I became sick

or

> We were going on a 12 day vacation. Three days in, ....

Comment: 4 hours into the 12 hours flight means after 4 hours of the flight, right?

Comment: Yes. The point was more that "in" often is used relative to some other defined time period

Answer (score 0):

It is another example of idiom born of lazy language usage. Using "in" in such context shortens the idea and depends on the implication of the previous part of the conversation. Using in for into the journey, into the process, into the treatment, etc. relieves the writer of repeating what may already have been said and understood,